# When ADF publish branch is git protected how to publish?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-git-deployment

ADF git mode recommends publishing to Master branch(or a fix branch which usually is protected from check-ins). Since Master is usually protected from check-ins and only pull requests are allowed, how would the publish work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Master` branch is used to publish ADF to `adf_publish` branch. In short, this process converts several json files into ARM-template json files stored in `adf_publish` branch. Other working banches need to be merged into `Master` branch and then be published together in `Master` branch.

Comment: Yes, we cannot create pull request to 'adf_publish branch'. We only can pull request from other 'working branches' to 'master branch' , then merge into 'master branch', then do publish at 'master branch'.

Comment: We can't merge these two branches manually via git. Only in ADF, when we run 'publish' at Master branch, the ADF will deploy the changes on Master branch to the ad_publish branch automatically(convert to ARM Template for storage).

Comment: removed my comments as issues were resolved

Comment: can the publish be done from main branch instead of master branch and then the templates are generated to adf_publish?