# Azure data factory working-branch confusion

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-git-deployment

Azure data factory introduces many branches in git mode.

1. Source branch : Save is stored here
2. Publish branch
3. working branch: After a git is connected, ADF prompts us for this.

What does the working branch do?

Comment: Did you team create this working branch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are three types of branches when we use git mode.

| Branch Name | Quantitiy | Use Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adf_publish | One and only one | save Resource Manager templates of the published factory |
| main | One and only one | this is collaboration branch used to merge changes of other working branches |
| working branch | multiple | everyone on the team works on these branches |

Comment: When we create a connection with git, it asks us which branch to save the change and the folder. This pretty much makes the working branch. Then why are we prompted for a 'working branch' ? If we select another working branch, where will it be saved?

Comment: Have you new a branch and then switch to this branch? Changes will be saved to the [current branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWrwF.png).