# ADF publish confusion in git mode

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-git-deployment

In git mode, when we want to test a pipeline, ADF forces us to publish first.
Publish action does two things is my understanding

1. Saves to the local ADF (DEV) as given [here](https://sqlplayer.net/2019/06/deployment-of-azure-data-factory-with-azure-devops/)
2. Creates arm templates in a branch (adf_publish/the branch we
   specify)

But to get the 'Publish' button enabled, we need to be in collaboration branch. This means no two people can work at the same time on a DEV ADF. As both people will be asked to publish by ADF before they could test the pipeline they are building.

If this is the case then why is there an option for us to connect another branch other than collaboration branch? (by changing it from the drop down)

Also what is a 'working branch'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know, we only can 'Publish' in collaboration branch and changes are being pushed to to "adf_publish" branch by default. By default, the collaboration branch is named `main`.

1. If you want team work, you need to create several branches.
   [image]
2. Working on the own branch, we can validate and debug the pipeline to make sure everything is ok.
   [image]
3. Then click `save all`, it will commit on the own branch. If we want publish, we need to creat a pull request to the `main` branch.
   [image]

4.After merged to the `main` branch, we can publish to the `adf_publish` branch.
[image]

Comment: At Step#2 : Validate and debug forces us to publish. Datafactory will not allow us to debug until and unless we publish it. That becomes a chicken and egg situation then, right?

Comment: No, only `trigger` to run the pipeline need to be published first, `debug` and `validate` don't need.