# Activating ADF Triggers without Publish

Tags: git, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

To create a Trigger, seems like you have to publish it before it can take effect. But publishing requires a PR to the 'Collaboration' branch, which means we will have to create a PR even before testing if the trigger actually works and also multiple subsequent PRs until we get the trigger right.

Especially when you want to develop Event Triggers based on file uploads, this is counter productive to create a PR even before you have tested the Trigger.

Is there a different way to set up ADF in the DEV environment or to activate a trigger without needing to publish it first?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't. We can't activate a trigger without publish it first. Unless you trigger the pipeline with other service, such as logic app.

Comment: so what is the recommended approach to developing triggers?

Comment: That's Data Factory built-in trigger limit. Logic app also have much triggers which can help you trigger the pipeline run, trigger+action(execute data factory pipeline).

Comment: Hi Gadam, you can ref answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822640/10549281

Comment: This is really a malor drawback, every time a PR is created it tiggers a CI/CD process and we can only approve a PR when is tested. How can you test your trigger in that way.

Comment: @PlayingWithBI that's where the different environments come into play. Normally you have at least a DEV and PRD environment. Once you publish to DEV, you test and check triggers work before publishing to PRD.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PowerShell query to Start and Stop ADF triggers, you can find the code to do the same [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/start-azurermdatafactoryv2trigger?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

PowerShell just need few details like your subscription details, resource group details where ADF exists and then ADF details. This can be controlled without having to publish the ADF, moreover you can create a generic script and save it for further use-case testing, this will save your time in future as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Gadam : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !

Comment: Start/Stop a trigger is like enable/disable, Start won't fire it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an other way can help achieve activate a trigger without needing to publish it first. @Joseph Xu provides more details for us.

You could ref the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822640/10549281