# Azure Synapse/Data Factory - When providing values to the ForEach widget, how can I run all the values simultaneusly to avoid wait time?

Tags: foreach, parallel-processing, azure-data-factory, lookup, azure-synapse

How can I run the multiple values passed to my ForEach simutaneosuly?

I intend to pass 100+ values from lookup to foreach, then the foreach to run all at the same time because the processing time is too large for the process to complete.

Description:

- The Lookup widget (1st Widget) passes multiple values.
- I want a way to run all the values passed by the lookup to the child pipeline to be run simultaneously.
- Currently it runs one after another.
- I have sequential mode off. I have increased the batch count to 20.

If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

[image]

I tried to pass the data in the array form, not worked, or maybe require more guidance. If there was a demo/video that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this with a trigger or using debug mode?  The pipeline will run the children sequentially if you're using debug to execute the pipeline.

As far as creating/running a trigger without publishing, these posts may help with that problem:
[ADF publish confusion in git mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817692/adf-publish-confusion-in-git-mode/65822640#65822640)

[Activating ADF Triggers without Publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819220/activating-adf-triggers-without-publish)

Comment: I am currently using the debug mode because I would be publishing the pipeline only when it would be working. Is there no other way to test without publishing, just to be sure?

Comment: I believe there's a warning message when you try to use debug to execute the parent pipeline stating as much.  Not sure if that has changed recently but I'm positive that debug mode will not run your pipeline in parallel (perhaps debug mode isn't set up for the scaling out required).  Is it possible to limit the lookup file's children two 'test' sources to

Comment: Let me publish the pipeline and then create triggers to run the pipeline and revert back.

Comment: It worked, I published the trigger and re-ran with updates of Batch Count.

Comment: Glad to hear.  They should probably make that clearer when the debugger is executing a pipeline activity within a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @[lcolbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12100000/lcolbert), that this is an expected behavior in ADF. When you try to debug a parent pipeline with the above flow, it will give the warning like below.

[image]

It will run in sequential by default because **debug won't handle such concurrent executions due to its scalability**.

It's only the case when you execute a child pipeline inside the ForEach. Whereas when you execute normal activities like **Set variable** in debug, you can see it handles the parallel runs.

[image]

So, to run your child pipeline in parallel through ForEach, you need to publish the pipeline changes and use trigger option.

There is no need to create a new trigger for this, you can trigger manually like below.

[image]

This will create parallel runs as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I published the trigger and re-ran with updates of Batch Count.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8YkM.png)